# Oracle SQL: JOIN between tables but just show columns from tablename1

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Is there a quick way of doing a JOING between two tables (tablename1 and tablename2) and just show the columns of the tablename1.

This is an example:

```
select * from tablename1 t1
left join tablename t2
on t2.id=t1.id
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the alias with the `*`

```
select t1.*
from tablename1 t1
  left join tablename2 t2 on t2.id=t1.id;
```

But that doesn't make sense because it will return the same result as

```
select t1.*
from tablename1 t1
```

**Edit**  jarlh is right: the second query will only return the same result if `id` is unique in `tablename2`

Comment: It would be useful if the join type was not `LEFT JOIN`. `INNER JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` or maybe even `FULL JOIN`.

Comment: Well, it could be useful, if for some reasons inside t2 is some kind of a filter

Comment: @frlan: as long as that is an outer join, the second one will return the same as the first one - regardless of any filter in the join condition.

Comment: Yes. I was thinking about an inner join (and to be honest, thought it would be the default join on Oracle if not explicit set)

Comment: @frlan: `left join` ***is*** an outer join - in every DBMS (as specified by the SQL standard)

Comment: The queries do not return the same result if there are duplicated id's in t2.

Comment: In addition, if t2.id has unique/primary key constraint Oracle will not do the join at all because the constraint guarantees max one matching row in t2. It's called table elimination optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify `t1.*` in you select list:

```
SELECT    t1.* -- here! 
FROM      tablename1 t1
LEFT JOIN tablename t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
```